# Can we find a regular cover for the set of integers with the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can we find a ***regular*** cover for the set of integers with a finite collection of congruence wherein every integer belong to at least one of the classes in the system and the system of congruence consists only of odd prime modulus, each modulus is repeated exactly twice and is greater or equal to 7?  Can I say that it is not possible since if a prime p divides one of the modulus, then it should divide at least p of them?

Comment: Could you include definition (or link to one) of regular cover? And what is the meaning of "each modulus is repeated exactly twice"?

Comment: Regular cover means that every integer belong to at least one of the congruence classes. Each modulus is repeated exactly twice means that each modulus in the collection of congruence is repeated exactly twice,   Example, the collection of congruence has the following moduli:  7, 7, 11, 11, 13, 13, 17, 17 etc.

Comment: Does $7,7$ for example mean it could be $7k+2$ or $7k=5$ to cover some of the integers? If not, what does it mean to repeat a modulus?

Comment: @coffeemath:  For example, can the union of the system of congruences below cover the set of integers?  n equivalent to:  2 mod 7, 5 mod 7, 3 mod 11, 8 mod 11, 5 mod 13, 11 mod 13, ... , 12 mod pk, 19 mod pk, where pk can be taken to be an arbitrarily large odd prime number.  We just choose the residues but each of the odd prime moduli are greater than or equal to 7 and each of them is repeated exactly twice as shown in the given example.

Answer (score 0):

Since the moduli $p_i$ are all at least $7,$ and we have used only two residue classes in the proposed covering for each modulus, we can choose a third residue class $c_i$ for each  mod $p_i.$ Then one can use Chinese remainder to get an $x$ with $x \equiv c_i$ mod $p_i$ for each of the (finitely many) $i$. This $x$ will not satisfy any of our proposed congruences in the cover.

Note the same argument works for any system of moduli which are pairwise coprime and all at least $3.$

Comment: But the question is that the system is supposed to have only two and only two residue classes for each pi.  With this restriction imposed, can we find a cover for the set of integers? Why and why not?

Comment: To be specific: let the two residue classes mod $p_i$ be $a_i,b_i.$ Then my proof goes by selecting, for each $p_i,$ some residue class *other than* $a_i,b_i,$ call it $c_i.$ Then apply Chinese Remainder Theorem to the system $x \equiv c_i$ mod $p_i.$ In your probem the $p_i$ are distinct primes so are pairwise coprime as needed for reminder theorem.

Comment: Oh, you are proving that such a system cannot be a cover for the set of integers?  So, the answer to my question is it cannot be a cover? My other question is: can I say that it cannot be a cover since if a prime p divides one of the modulus, then it should divide at least p of them?  Is that a valid reason?

Comment: I don't think your approach in your comment works. All the primes use for moduli are distinct, so one can't say "if a prime divides one modulus it divides at least $p$ of them". You already stipulated each prime modulus is there exactly twice, which is less than $p$ since $p \ge 7.$

Comment: The primes use for moduli are not distinct since each of the moduli is repeated twice. Let M={7, 11, 13, 17, ... pk}. Let p belong to set M. E.g. p = 7. Since p divides one of the modulus (namely, 7), then it should divide at least 7 of the moduli in the system. However, p can only divide 2 of them in the system since 7 is repeated twice. Thus, we conclude it cannot cover the set of integers.

Comment: Not distinct, but collection of primes used is a multiset with each prime used there twice only. And since each is seven or more, no single prime $p$ can divide $p$ or more moduli. Maybe what you're saying is the basic fact that to get all integers in at least one class mod $p$ one needs at least $p$ classes. But that isn't how you set up your main question.